# Авторизация в FB и VK

Tags: facebook, objective-c, ios, vkontakte-api, ios7

Что-то мне вообще не везет с соцсетями (ios 8).

1. Фейсбук. Скачал фреймворк, добавил в проект, прописал схему для приложения ФБ. Логинится нормально, но не использует методы делегата `FBLoginViewDelegate`. В аппДелегате класс [FBLoginView class] прописал, добавил также дополнительный метод и прописал схемы в info.plist.
2. С ВК тоже непонятно. Скачал СДК Vkontakte iOS SDK LV и делаю по примеру [ссылка](https://andrewshmig.github.io/Vkontakte-iOS-SDK-LV/). Доходит до момента, когда нас предупреждают о том, что никому не передавайте свой адрес и т.д. Все.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VK рекомендуют использовать для авторизации [OAuth-авторизацию](https://vk.com/dev/authentication). SDK в прошлом

Comment: C FB разобрался. С ВК буду пробовать другие приемы.

Comment: Пост устарел. Текст из нынешнего описания: `Если Вы разрабатываете приложение для iOS, Android или Windows Phone, мы рекомендуем использовать наши мобильные SDK с возможностью авторизации через официальное приложение, установленное на устройстве клиента.`

Answer (score 1):

«никому не передавайте свой адрес» — имеется в виду «Не копируйте содержимое адресной строки»? Тогда вы на правильном пути. Нужно получить содержание этой адресной строки – там ваш токен для приложения – и можно закрывать web view.